# Drupal Migrate doesn't register

Tags: migrations

When trying to set up a migration, I can't seem to register new Migrations. When running `drush migrate-status`, I only see my User migration, even after a `drush migrate-register`.

My `migrate.inc` looks like this:

```
function module_migrate_api() {
    $api = array(
        'api' => 2,
        'migrations' => array(
            'User' => array(
                'class_name' => 'UserMigration'
            ),
            'News' => array(
                'class_name' => 'NewsMigration'
            ),
            'Activity' => array(
                'class_name' => 'ActivityMigration'
            )
        )
    );

    return $api;
}
```

And my `module.inc` file contains classes for each of these Migrations, based off of the `UserMigration` I wrote first (example given is `UserMigration`, which works, and `NewsMigration`, which does not work):

```
class UserMigration extends TestMigration {
    public function __construct($arguments) {
        parent::__construct($arguments);

        $this->description = t('Migrates users');

        $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'original')
            ->select('users')
            ->fields('users', array(
                'user_id',
                'username',
                'firstname',
                'lastname'
            ));
        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

        $options = array();
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser($options);

        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, array(
            'user_id' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => t('Source ID')
            )
        ), MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema());
    }

class NewsMigration extends TestMigration {
    public function __construct($arguments) {
        parent::__construct($arguments);

        $this->description = t('Migrates news');

        $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'original')
            ->select('news')
            ->fields('news', array(
                'news_id',
                'user_id',
                'title',
                'text'
            ));
        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

        $options = array();
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('news');

        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, array(
            'news_id' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => t('Source ID')
            )
        ), MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema());

        /* $this->addFieldMapping('target', 'source'); */
    }
}
```

So far, I haven't added fieldmappings, since I want to set up everything that should be migrated first, to get a complete view of the work that's left.

When running `drush migrate-register`, I'm getting the following output:

```
All statically defined migrations have been (re)registered.                                                                                                                                         [success]
```

And a `drush migrate-status` gives me the following:

```
 Group: Test  Total  Imported  Unprocessed  Status  Last imported
 User         55     0         55           Idle    2015-12-03 13:40:30
```

So as you can see, no errors, not even when running with -v. But only User is recognized. Both classes are in the same file. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Are you sure the first class is properly closed, I believe there an accolade '}' missing.

Comment: That error is on the other side of the keyboard, I forgot to copy it when cleaning up the code I pasted here.

Comment: I assume you got this worked out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear your cache (`drush cc all`) after (re)registering your classes.  Not doing so will often result in the migrate page showing error ClassName no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to specify the exact name, e.g.

```
drush migrate-register NewsMigration
```

If won't work, clear cache and restart your memcached if in use.

Also when sometimes re-registering the class, but you should try unregister and register it again, e.g.

```
drush migrate-reset-status User
drush migrate-deregister User
drush migrate-register User
```

Using `deregister` will remove the old `migrate_map_%` table and `register` should recreate it. See also this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/210805/1908) for further suggestions.