# Unknown map column when migrating users from CSV file

Tags: 7, migrations, importing-exporting

I'm trying to import the users from CSV file, but the import fails with the following error:

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'map.sourceid4' in 'where clause', in includes/database/database.inc:2171

Migrate class is:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Class for migrating users from a CSV file.
 */

/**
 * Class FooMigrateUsers.
 */
class FooMigrateUsers extends Migration {


  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->description = t('Foo users from CSV file');

    // Create the migrate source.
    $import_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'foo_migrate') . '/import/users.csv';
    $options = array(
      'header_rows' => 1,
    );

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV($import_path, array(), $options);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser();

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
        array(
          'Title' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 15,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Title',
          ),
          'Firstname' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 35,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'First name',
          ),
          'Lastname' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 35,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Last name',
          ),
          'Primary email address' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 80,
            'not null' => TRUE,
            'description' => 'Primary email address',
          ),
        ),
        MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema()
        );

    // Mapped fields

    // We must have a unique username in the Drupal 'users' table.
    // dedupe() takes the Drupal table and column for determining uniqueness.
    $this->addFieldMapping('name', 'Primary email address')
         ->dedupe('users', 'name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('mail', 'Primary email address')
         ->dedupe('users', 'mail');

    //$this->addFieldMapping('pass', 'password');

    // Apply default role.
    $this->addFieldMapping('roles')
         ->defaultValue(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID);

    $this->addFieldMapping('field_user_first_name',      'Firstname');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_user_last_name',       'Lastname');

    $this->addUnmigratedSources(array('Title'));

    $this->addUnmigratedDestinations(array(
      'access',
      'created',
      'data',
      'is_new',
      'language',
      'login',
      'pass',
      'picture',
      'role_names',
      'signature',
      'signature_format',
      'theme',
      'timezone',
    ));

  }

  /**
   * Modifies the row to be imported.
   *
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  public function prepareRow($row) {
    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }

}
```

The CSV data is like:

```
"Title","Firstname","Lastname","Primary email address"
"Mr","Foo","Bar","foo@example.com"
"Mrs","Bar","Foo","bar@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Column not found' (map.sourceid4) error sounds like migration table related to source mapping is not complete.

You should identify the table (e.g. using drush command):

```
drush sqlq "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'migrate_map_%'"
```

<sup>Note: You can also execute above in SQL editor by using quoted part only.</sup>

and check the list of available columns for that table:

```
$ drush sqlq "DESC migrate_map_foomigrateusers"
sourceid1   varchar(128)    NO  PRI NULL
sourceid2   varchar(128)    NO  PRI NULL
sourceid3   varchar(128)    NO  PRI NULL
destid1 int(10) unsigned    YES     NULL
needs_update    tinyint(3) unsigned NO      0
rollback_action tinyint(3) unsigned NO      0
last_imported   int(10) unsigned    NO      0
hash    varchar(32) YES     NULL
```

The number of `sourceidX` column should match with number of columns in CSV file. If they won't, probably you've modified the CSV file and after each structure change you have to re-register your migration class (see: `hook_migrate_api`).

So please reregister any statically defined migration classes by (check list by `drush ms`):

```
drush migrate-deregister FooMigrateUsers
drush migrate-register FooMigrateUsers
```

In case of further problems, these drush commands can be handy as well:

```
drush migrate-mappings --all # To verify mapping.
drush migrate-fields-source --all # To list source field mapping.
```

When ready, try re-importing the data again:

```
drush mi FooMigrateUsers
```